# How programtically exchange the authorization code to get the access token from cognito using python

Tags: python-3.x, api, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I been searching for a solution on how to exchange authorization_code to get the access token from cognito pragmatically . i have created cognito pool and integrated app client. so when i invoke the login domain in the below format, iam getting the login page and able to login/sign up

```
https://<your_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_app_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_callback_url>
```

Now the above url will return the authorization_code as parameter. I used post man to get the result with following query, which return the id token, acccess token, refresh token.

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token&
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=myid&
code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/login
```

Now  i would need to implement the same in my app to get the access token 
Below is the code i tried

```
 response = requests.post(url + '/oauth2/token',
                             auth=(App_client_id),
                             data={'grant_type': grant_type, 'code': accessCode, 'client_id': App_client_id,
                                   "redirect_uri":'http://localhost:5000/login'})
print(response.json())
```

But i am not getting any response.

### Expected: I am looking how to implement below use cases

1. I have an api-gatway associated with the cognito userpool/authorizer and this api-gateway return response from other aws services such as lambda.

2.In my application - Flask App, i want to put a logic in such a way that once user authenticated with the user pool after login, it return the authorization_code in the redirect_uri.

3. In the redirect_uri, i have certain ops- read/write/delete task. For each task, i need to authenticate with the access token which received through the authorization_code exchange. so only the user who logined can do the operation from the redirect uri.

Appreciate if anyone can help to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: have you added the header Authorization containing the Base64 encoded result of `clientId + ":" + secret` into the request?

Comment: Hi @HenriqueDroog, i added only client id as suggested in the document

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

where it suggest to pass client id as its 'Authorization code grant' type

Comment: I believe only the clientId and not Base64 encoded won't work. I believe both clientID and secret mist be used to get Base64 encoded like the authorization section mention https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html#post-token-request-parameters. However I am not sure how that would be if your client wasn't issued with a secret.

Comment: Hi @HenriqueDroog.. I have updated question with the expected use case that i am looking forward to implement. As i mentioned, i am able to get the token using POST man with the above parameters. And i am not looking for the 'Implict Grant ' type where i don't want to expose the token in the response. Please correct me if my approach is wrong in such cases.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else stuck on getting this to work, I found it worked using the `params` argument in `requests.post`

```
token_url="https://myapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
message = bytes(f"{client_id}:{client_secret}",'utf-8')
secret_hash = base64.b64encode(message).decode()
payload = {
    "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
    "client_id": client_id,
    "code": code,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": f"Basic {secret_hash}"}
           
resp = requests.post(token_url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you so much. I might add, being new to "requests", that the output of the token is, in this case above, not resp, but resp.text. I was hung up on that for a couple of hours. resp is only the status. ug :) Seeing that token hit the screen after outputting resp.text was like ambrosia for the eyes.

Comment: for some reason even this is not working for me. is there any config I need to check in coganito

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you got this working in POSTMAN but not in your Python code. As a result, you will need to ensure you copy everything from your request in POSTMAN over to your request from your script.

For example, are you setting the Content Type header to Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in your Python request. I do not believe so.

Additionally, if you do not have an app client secret associated with your Cognito App Client, you do not send an Authorization header. I am not too familiar with the requests library but I do not believe you need the following 'auth=(App_client_id),'.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

> If the client was issued a secret, the client must pass
>   its client_id and client_secret in the authorization header through
>   Basic HTTP authorization. The secret is Basic
>   Base64Encode(client_id:client_secret).

Comment: Hi @callo, i got the answer finally.. please let me know if you have any suggestion.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finlay got the way to exchange Authorization code to retrieve the access_token along with the refresh and id_token from cognito auth with below code:

```
response = requests.post(url + '/oauth2/token',{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'grant_type': grant_type, 'client_id': App_client_id,  'code': code, 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/login'})
print(response.json())
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you get `code` ? - edit: interactively, if I understand your question.