# How do I log in a user and use my Amplify GraphQL endpoint in Python?

Tags: python, authentication, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

What is the process for logging in a user (with their e-mail and password) and using the returned credentials to perform an Amplify GraphQL query using `requests` in Python (3.9+)?

I can't find an example anywhere of how to do this. All the examples I've fond use (a variety of) different credentials, entered manually, but it's unclear how to get these in the first place, in particular from just a user's login.

E.g., the scenario is I have a data science with an account with (read) access to the GraphQL API using a Python JupyterLab notebook, and I want them to be able to simply provide their login info and then do analysis. How is that done?

Comment: User authentication for amplify is typically done via AWS cognito. Have you already configured authentication like described here? https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#authentication-with-amplify

Comment: @jordanm Yes, sorry should have mentioned. Cognito is part of my Amplify project and all the necessary permissions are associated with the data model. It all works fine in my JavaScript app (user logs in, access is established, permissions are enforced, etc.) but I can't figure out how to implement (effectively) the same workflow in Python.

Comment: Cognito uses oauth2 for its authentication process. There is a question and answer here doing manually with requests: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62171090/1032785. Also there is this library you may find useful: https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1/client.html